# Can I ask about the possible design of a proprietary software given the observed behavior?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, design, scope

I've written a question along the lines of "How does WhatsApp's [*View Once*](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1077018839582332) feature work", where I ask what the existence of such a feature implies in terms of API offered by the OS and used by WhatsApp.

I'm not going to ask a generic question about design principles, but a question about how WhatsApp (well, some aspect of it) is designed and what the OS on which it runs has to support for that feature to be possible. Specifically, I'd add code snippets to explain what my hypothesis is, in terms of what functions I expect the OS to expose and what WhatsApp functions would make use of those and how.

Would this be an on-topic question? Or should I maybe ask it on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: So you have a hypothesis on how the feature works and what functions are exposed by the OS that allow that to happen. What is your question specifically then? Whether that is how WhatsApp implements it? Or are you asking for the existence of the functions that you assumed the OS exposes? One thing you should note if you want to ask it is to make it not specific to WhatsApps implementation (That would be off-topic since only they can answer that)

Comment: This does not sound like a good fit for Stack Overflow. An authoritative answer can only come from WhatsApp themselves, but they are probably reluctant to confirm or deny any speculations about the internals of their proprietary software.

Comment: Depending on the question and how you present it, it *might* be on-topic on end-user sites like [android.se] (e.g. [WhatsApp view once video - what is the file location in Android file system?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/251075/44325)), as long as it's asking a specific issue and not asking for code. Otherwise, I know there's a site focusing on [reverseengineering.se], but not sure if such a question is allowed there unless you're really trying to reverse-engineer it.

Comment: Don't ask about a specific solution, just ask for general solutions and simply narrow the scope accordingly. So instead of asking "how does app X achieve effect Y" simply ask "how can I achieve an effect like Y in app X". That is on topic and allows for even better solutions than implemented in this app.

Answer (score 13):

You have a question of which parts are on-topic and interesting for later readers, for example:

- How to prevent users from taking screenshots in my Android app?
- How can I show an image in my iOS app without downloading it to the user's Pictures library?
- Given such-and-so messaging protocol, how do I create a message indicating that a user has viewed some media?
- Using this-and-that cloud storage, how to delete media after X days?

And so on. Those are implementation questions that are answerable, on-topic and helpful for later readers.

It's just that all of those together are not focused enough.

Answer (score 8):

It's off-topic because ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) It's unclear why you need to know this beyond idle curiosity. (If you're trying to solve a specific problem, such as implementing something similar yourself, you should ask about that instead).

This question also appears to be speculative (since only WhatsApp can state authoritatively how it was implemented). See also: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: I will disagree with that. Even though the question seems speculative, the answer is pretty much a fact: It doesn't matter what services any given OS has to offer, this feature will always be a best effort, and not ever can be implemented as a binding contract.

Comment: @IInspectable There is a factual answer, but only WhatsApp can authoritatively confirm the answer, so this is effectively a [customer service question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: That's a different, less useful question. But it's an answerable question nevertheless.

Comment: [so] isn't customer service though, @IInspectable . [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: The "ask that other question" instead part cannot be emphasized enough. Typically people don't really want to know how something was done by some specific entity, they just want to know how somebody can do something so that it works really well.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Yes, that's my thought. If the OP wants to know so that they can do the same thing, they should just ask about that instead. If they're not trying to do something similar themselves, though, it isn't a practical, answerable question based on a problem that they actually face.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I agree with IInspectable here, it can be rephrased into a more objective question like "Is it technically possible for View Once feature in WhatsApp to be implemented without <this API> being exposed by the OS?" or, if it's a bit contrived, it can be made into a concern about privacy: "Does the View Once feature in WhatsApp breaks <this privacy concern>?"

Comment: @ThomA That's under the premise, that this actually were a *"customer service question"*, and only the vendor could give an authoritative answer. This is not the case, though. Literally anyone can look at the code and see how it's implemented.

Comment: _It's unclear why you need to know this beyond idle curiosity_ Where is it stated that idle curiosity-driven questions are off-topic?

Comment: @Enlico i disagree that they're defacto off-topic (no such off-topic close reason exists), but they're unlikely to be received well, which is the entire point of that line in the asking guidelines. That doesn't mean your question can't be off topic for other reasons just because it's asking an idle curiosity-driven question, such as lacking focus or being unclear.

Comment: @Enlico The “don’t ask” document in the help center states that you should only ask practical, answerable questions about actual problems that they face. This is not a practical question, it’s not answerable, and it isn’t about a problem that the OP actually faces.